# Trouble Targetting Div to Change Height Using Percentages

Tags: html, css

I would like my home page for a website to be responsive across multiple screens (& thus I have been told to use percentages) and I want the website to consist of four parts:

1. A Navigation Bar at the top of the screen that stretches to the edges of the screen on both sides, including the top. To make this simple, I'll have the background color be black. [Approx. 10% of the height of the page from the top]
2. Then I want an area of content in the "Middle" portion of the homepage with a background color of green. [60%]
3. Towards the bottom I want a smaller area with a background color of blue. [20%]
4. A Footer the same size as the navigation bar that has a color of black as well. [10%]

My problem is this:
- How do I target, or what do I need to do to have the div's inside of the main and footer tags be the colors I want them to be and their respective heights?

P.S. I am capable of changing the background color for the navigation bar, but nothing for the main or footer elements works.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--Header Stuff-->
</head>
<body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nav id="navigaton_bar">
                <!--Navigation Stuff-->
            </nav>
            <main>
                <div class="home_body">
                    <!--Content-->
                </div>
                <div class="lower_home_body">
                    <!--Content-->
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer class="footer_bar">
                <!--Footer Stuff-->
            </footer>
       </div> <!--END OF WRAPPER-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS Code:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
#navigation_bar {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    }
.home_body {
    background-color: green;
    height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
    }
.lower_home_body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: blue;
    }
.footer_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: black;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems with your code:

1. Typo in id attribute of nav: `navigaton_bar` (vs. `navigation_bar` in CSS).
2. You need to set height to 100% for the `wrapper` element.
3. You need to set height to 80% for the `main` element, and then use 75% and 25% for the two contained divs in order to achieve 60% and 20% of the overall page height.
4. You shouldn't have absolute positioning on the navigation bar.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    height:100%;
}
#navigation_bar {
    background-color: black;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}
main {
    height:80%;
}
.home_body {
    background-color: green;
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
}
.lower_home_body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.footer_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
     <nav id="navigation_bar">
         <!--Navigation Stuff-->
     </nav>
     <main>
         <div class="home_body">
             <!--Content-->
         </div>
         <div class="lower_home_body">
             <!--Content-->
         </div>
     </main>
     <footer class="footer_bar">
         <!--Footer Stuff-->
     </footer>
</div> <!--END OF WRAPPER-->
```

Comment: thank you very much for your timely response. However, I have just one last question: if I wanted to increase the size of the home_body how can i do that without exceeding 100% or having to shrink a different div?

Comment: From my knowledge, that is not possible using the normal CSS `height` property. However, if you use the [flexbox layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), then you can use the `flex-grow` property to selectively increase/decrease the relative size of each item in a column (or row, if using a horizontal direction). Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vd8fywqd/.

Answer (score 0):

I learn more every day, but so far, I have learned responsive design in CSS uses percentages for width of the page, not height.

Responsiveness usually involves beginning the design in the mobile screen size, then adding content as the screen size gets larger. It also means that users usually scroll down to see more and nav bar items that would be horizontal on a full-sized desktop would be stacked on top of each other on a mobile screen size, or minimized and represented by an icon or "menu", to be touched by the user, thereby displaying a stacked menu.

[Hope this link helps.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp)

Add basic divs and content to the html file, then start styling with the CSS file for color and height.

Answer (score 0):

Try vh instead of %, for example

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    }
#navigation_bar {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100%;
    }
.home_body {
    background-color: green;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    }
.lower_home_body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20vh;
    background-color: blue;
    }
.footer_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: black;
    }
```